# Google Analytics Page Speed Implementation

Tags: google-analytics

I am wondering how to implement correctly google analytics page speed measurements and how to change the sample size correctly:
As seen below in the code box we currently Google analytics including eCommerce running on our site. Now I would like to also increase the sample sizeof speed tracking (the percentage of pageviews used for speedtracking, usually 1%) to 100% on our staging system.

As far as I understood I can do that by following [this instructions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate).
My question not is if I just add it to the existing create method in my analytics snippet or do I have to create another method below.

If I understood correctly I would now do this: 
replace

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'ricomprostaging.it');
```

with

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', {'sampleRate': 5}, 'ricomprostaging.it');
```

Please advise if I am on the right track. I have placed the entire code of the current snippet below.

Thank you,

Fabian

```
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'ricomprostaging.it');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('send', 'pageview', 'search_query');
    ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

    function trackEcommerce() {
    this._addTrans = addTrans;
    this._addItem = addItems;
    this._trackTrans = trackTrans;
    }
    function addTrans(orderID,store,total,tax,shipping,city,state,country) {
    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id': orderID,
        'affiliation': store,
        'revenue': total,
        'tax': tax,
        'shipping': shipping,
        'city': city,
        'state': state,
        'country': country
    });
    }
    function addItems(orderID,sku,product,variation,price,qty) {
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': orderID,
        'sku': sku,
        'name': product,
        'category': variation,
        'price': price,
        'quantity': qty
    });
    }
    function trackTrans() {
        ga('ecommerce:send');
    }
    var pageTracker = new trackEcommerce();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you need to replace the `create` statement on all pages**. **However `sampleRate` is the wrong option**: this option defines the sample rate for Google Analytics as a whole. For sampling speed, you want to use `siteSpeedSampleRate`. As for the code, I would use the following:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', {
    'siteSpeedSampleRate': 5,
    'cookieDomain': 'ricomprostaging.it'
});
```